# can't pass optional arguments to a \newenvironment using fancyvrb

Tags: environments, verbatim, optional-arguments, preamble, fancyvrb

I am trying to define a new `script` environment built on `fancyvrb`'s `Verbatim` environment.

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newenvironment{script}[1][firstnumber=1]
               {\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{Verbatim}
               [frame=single,numbers=left,framerule=0.4mm,{#1}]}
               {\end{Verbatim}}
```

The `script` environment is meant to be used like this:

```
\begin{script}
(1st line of code)
(2nd line of code)
\end{script}

some text

\begin{script}[firstnumber=3]
(3rd line of code)
\end{script}
```

but this fails to compile, producing the following error messages:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                    
l.6846 ... function is needed to show intermediate
                                                  
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `## the 'print' function is needed to show intermediate' bet
ween \begin{script}[<key=value>] and line end
.
```

Is there an error in my code or a bug in `fancyvrb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the documentation of `fancyvrb` more carefully. Here is the solution (preamble):

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{script}{Verbatim}
               {frame=single,numbers=left,framerule=0.4mm}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to define a verbatim environment, use the appropriate command:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{script}{Verbatim}{
  frame=single,
  numbers=left,
  framerule=0.4mm,
  firstnumber=1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{script}
(1st line of code)
(2nd line of code)
\end{script}

some text

\begin{script}[firstnumber=3]
(3rd line of code)
\end{script}

\end{document}
```

[image]